# how to change the visual state of a WPF control based on evaluation of other Visual Elements?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

I want to do the following:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Result}">
```

I want to Color this based on an equality check on Result, what's the view centric way to do this?  I remember reading about template selector, is that the right choice here?

example:

```
Text="Pass" Color="Green"
Text="Fail" Color="Red"
```

I'd like this to be dynamic so that if Text Changes it is re-evaluated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use triggers inside a style:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Result}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Result}" Value="Pass">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Result}" Value="Fail">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Alternatively you could create an [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) implementation which converts strings to brushes (according to your rules) and use a binding directly:

```
<TextBlock
    Text="{Binding Result}"
    Foreground="{Binding Result,Converter={StaticResource my:ResultBrushConverter}} />
```

I won't go into details for this option because I think the pure-XAML option is the better way to go.

Comment: The trigger approach is interesting, I'll start doing it that way to. Is there any disadvantage over the Converter approach?

Comment: A converter would be a bit more flexible since it's code based. For example, if you needed to change the colour based on a Regex pattern in the text, a converter would make that possible.